# Poetry managing environment System python

Tags: python, python-poetry

When I run `poetry env info` - I get the following:

```
Virtualenv
Python:         3.9.13
Implementation: CPython
Path:           /Users/me/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/my.project-NEejG4ix-py3.9
Valid:          True

System
Platform: darwin
OS:       posix
Python:   /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9
```

What is the `System` and how does the `System` Python get set ?

Answer (score 2):

Your platform and OS are basic software information. As it says, you're on a Mac (Darwin) and all Macs have a POSIX interface.

The Python path comes from whereever within your macOS you've got Python installed.

All of these details can be found in the Python `os` module methods

Comment: What if you want to use a different Python path for poetry? Is that path only for install - once it's installed doesn't it use the path in the actual virtual environment?

Comment: @Ryan You would need to install poetry into the other Python interpreter's libraries. Any virtualenv would inherit its parents libraries, by default